# tmux is causing anaconda to use a different python source

Tags: python, tmux

Ok, so I am in my anaconda environment and I ran which python. I get

```
/home/comp/anaconda3/envs/env1/bin/python
```

Now if I start tmux, then run source activate env1, then which python, I get

```
/home/comp/anaconda3/bin/python
```

even though I do have my environment activated. How can I make anaconda see the same path inside tmux ?

Answer (score 32):

The solution seems to be to deactivate the conda environment, then start tmux, then reactivate the environment inside tmux.

Comment: Weird solution but works ...

Comment: That's weird indeed.

Comment: I'm upvoting because this is the solution that worked for me, however it is really a far from ideal solution

Comment: worked for me, is there a more permanent solution?

Comment: didn't work for me on MacOS

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but I really didn't like any of the solutions since they involved deactivating and activating Conda every time I load into `tmux`. So instead, I added what is below to my `.tmux.conf`:

IMPORTANT EDIT: This code works for me, as I'm currently running a zsh shell and this is where my settings are stored. Your standard shell might be different, to find your shell location use the command `echo "$SHELL"` and replace the `/bin/zsh`in my answer with your own shell path.

```
set -g default-command "/bin/zsh"
```

Once done, just resource your `.tmux.conf` file and the changes should be activate. This should allow `tmux` to load whatever settings you have in your `.bash_profile` including Conda.

Comment: Please don't assume that his shell is `zsh` (he doesn't mention it). If people without it use your answer they may have issues. Perhaps you should also explain a little more on why does it solve the issue, like what is `-g` there, what the default value does, etc...

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about people with other shells at all. I'll change up the answer to clarify that.

Comment: A more general answer might be `set -g default-command "${SHELL}"` (I am not sure whether $SHELL is supposed to always be set by shells, but I expect this to often work).

Comment: Note to anyone trying this: without killing my tmux server and all running sessions, this only worked for me when I created a new session, but not when I created new windows or panes within that session. Upon restarting everything this worked great.

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour is caused by TMux sourcing `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`. My `~/.profile` is this:

```bsh
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

You can see that **first** `~/.bashrc` is sourced and **then** `~/bin` and `~/.local/bin` are **prepended**. [As I experienced myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698497/conda-does-not-set-paths-when-activating-environment/57707711#57707711), this causes `conda` to hickup.

The solution would be to comment out the two blocks manipulating PATH in `~/.profile`.

**Edit (2019/09/24):** An even better seems to be to configure TMux such that it does not spawn a login shell but just a normal one. See the answers for the linked question.

Comment: For reference, for preventing tmux from spawning a login shell: https://superuser.com/a/1330842/72533.

Answer (score 3):

Running:

```
conda activate env1
```

Instead of:

```
source activate env1
```

When inside tmux worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The following happens to me after starting a Tmux session (without conda having any active env).

When I first do inside the Tmux session:

```bsh
conda activate myEnv
```

I get

```bsh
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

If instead I do:

```bsh
source deactivate
conda activate myEnv
```

Everything works just fine. `which python` points to the correct path.

Answer (score 2):

I find that tmux will always call the profile for your shell, not just the rc. So if you are using bash like I do, it will call /etc/profile, which will have a call to path_helper.

In order to fix this, change `/etc/profile` to:

```
if [[ -z $TMUX ]] && [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

If you are using bash, also change any `export PATH=$PATH:/foo` in `.bashrc` to

```
if [[ -z $TMUX ]]; then
  export PATH=$PATH:/foo
fi
```

then you restart the terminal(for example Iterm). Everything should be good!

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable tmux from spawning login shell as described in [tmux is causing anaconda to use a different python source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366553/tmux-is-causing-anaconda-to-use-a-different-python-source/673196#673196superuser.com/a/1330842/72533)

Comment: well, you're referencing this same post in your answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a fully automated way to do it so you don't have to manually deactivate and activate the environment each time. It's a combination of some of the other answers here. The first step is to open your `.tmux.conf` file and find the line `set -g default-command` and add to it so that it says `set -g default-command "${SHELL}"` (Note: It might also say `set-option -g default-command`; `set` is an alias of `set-option`, so either is fine).

Then, in your initialization scripts, after the conda initialize section that conda automatically adds, you'll need to deactivate and then re-activate your conda. Here's one way to do that:

I recommend people use a `.profile` file to customize their environment. To do that, you can `source .profile` from your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` file (depending on which shell you use). Then, take the conda initialization script that conda added and put it in `.profile`. Then, after this, add `conda deactivate` and `conda activate my_conda_env`. Following the conda initialization, it should look like:

```
# <<< conda initialize <<<
conda deactivate
conda activate my_conda_env
```

It doesn't work without the `conda deactivate` step, so be sure to include that.

You can test that this is working by entering `which python` after you enter tmux and ensuring that it points to the correct python in your conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following lines:

```
source deactivate env1
source activate env1
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When running `conda activate` before, I was being told 'CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run...'

The fix for me was a simplification of the answer of @jose.marcos.rf (I lack commenting privileges).

All that was needed was to source the `conda.sh` file from my `.bash_profile` file. In my .bash_profile I have the following:

```
if [[ ! -z $TMUX ]]; then
    # Enable `conda activate` and such within Tmux
    . "/usr/local/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
fi
```

Then, opening a new Tmux session and running `conda activate` works as expected.