# Why does conda fail inside tmux even though it works in bash?

Tags: tmux

My newly setup conda fails when I try to activate an existing environment inside tmux. Apparently it finds the conda binary but cannot run the command. Inside bash it works as expected.

**Steps**:

1. Open bash
2. Check that conda activate works in bash
3. Open tmux
4. Run conda activate in tmux, output below

   xxx@xxx:~$ conda activate
   CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
   To initialize your shell, run

   ```
    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
   ```

   Currently supported shells are:

   - bash
   - fish
   - tcsh
   - xonsh
   - zsh
   - powershell

   See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

   IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.

Comment: Probably related: [Why are interactive shells on OSX login shells by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119627)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366553/tmux-is-causing-anaconda-to-use-a-different-python-source/).

The problem is I'm running tmux on a server with an interactive login shell, for details see [.bashrc vs .bash_profile](https://linuxize.com/post/bashrc-vs-bash-profile/). Bash in this case only opens .bash_profile. So this means there are two solutions to the problem:

1. **Import .bashrc in .bash_profile, e.g. by adding**

   ```
    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
    fi
   ```
2. **Moving the conda init code block from .bashrc to .bash_profile**

Edit: Updated with the comment of Kusalananda, thanks for the explanations.

Comment: No, `tmux` does not use `.bashrc` for initialisation, it starts a `bash` shell, and that shell reads `.bashrc` upon startup. The reason you `.bashrc` file isn't parsed might be that you either 1) don't use `bash`, or 2) (more likely) you use macOS and your `.bash_profile` file does not source `.bashrc`.  Note: `tmux` does not care about your shell, and never has. To `tmux`, your shell is just some application that it starts when you haven't told it to do anything else.

Comment: Good to know. Feel free to add a source or correct my comment directly, I only know about the problem, nothing about tmux.
Also nope that is an Ubuntu server, so your comment is incorrect there. I can add the details to the question if necessary but this does not only happen on MacOs.
Also default shell is bash and bash also starts, so I tested that as well

Comment: The second part is correct though - .bash_profile does not include .bashrc, so that would surely be another working solution

Comment: The first part could well be correct if `tmux` starts a login shell. A `bash` login shell would parse `.bash_profile` but not `.bashrc` unless it is explicitly sourced from `.bash_profile` (which it often is). In any case, `tmux` does not use `.bashrc` nor `.bash_profile`. It does not care. It is the shell that uses either or both of these depending on its configuration on your OS, whatever OS you use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I updated my answer including a source and adding the second solution